# Why isn't my Moto G showing up on my lapto

Tags: usb, motorola-moto-g, mtp

Moto G not showing up on PC. But gets charged all right. Tried changing the cable and plugging on another PC. Out of luck. Turned on USB debugging. Still isn't working. Any ideas?